# Referencing Blazor server project from a Web API project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor-server-side

I have an existing Asp.Net Core WebAPI project which I want to add UI to it, using Server Side Blazor. For obvious maintainability reason, I prefer that the Blazor code would be in a separate project (`.csproj`) in the same solution, though I want the UI to be served from the same service, using a dedicated route (`/ui`).

I started by creating the Blazor project as a separate project (with its own `Main` etc, using built-in Visual Studio template for Blazor app), and now I'm trying to reference the new Blazor project from the original WebAPI project, and combine their "main" methods into one.

After some struggles, I sort of managed to make it work, but when the browser renders the page, it gets 404 on few files: `<myBlazorApp>.styles.css`, `blazor.server.js` and `open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css`:
[image]

Here's what I did:

1. In the WebAPI project I added a project reference to the Blazor project
2. In the Blazor project's csproj, I added `<OutputType>Library</OutputType>` to the `<PropertyGroup>` section (and removed `Program.cs`)
3. In the same file I added the following section:

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Include="wwwroot/**" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

4. To the WebAPI's `Main` I added:

```cs
services.AddRazorPages();
services.AddServerSideBlazor(o => o.DetailedErrors = true);
```

And:

```cs
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(UserManagerUI.App).Assembly,
                "myBlazorNamespace.wwwroot"),
});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
```

**UPDATE**:
I checked it also in a clean solution with only a WebAPI and Blazor projects and got exactly the same result, so the following note is irrelevant:

<s>**Note**: the real story is a bit more complicated, but I'm not sure it's relevant: The WebAPI project is itself a class library which is used as a NuGet in few projects in other repositories. (the `Main` of the WebAPI mentioned above is actually a different method that is called from the other project's `Main`). The reason I'm still mentioning this, is that this is also the reason I prefer to have the `wwwroot` folder as an embedded resource, and not as regular files, as it's easier to package it in a NuGet.</s>

Comment: The question is unclear and frankly, backwards. In all web projects, no matter the stack, the UI project calls the API project, not the other way around. To see how this should be done use the [.NET Aspire templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/get-started/aspire-overview) which create a Blazor project, API project and connect one to another. Plus they add a dashboard for logs and metrics and configure Docker, but that's essentially transparent to you

Comment: Indeed this project is not the most "standard" for few reasons I won't get into, but it's related to my last comment that this is a NuGet library. The WebAPI is the primary NuGet that other projects reference to create unique Web API services (with a lot of common behavior), and the UI is secondary, only for more user-friendly administration purposes, instead of using PostMan. I hope that makes more sense now. Anyway, if something in the question is unclear, please let me know what should I clarify and I'll edit it.

Comment: So you're trying to replicate Swagger UI? For multiple services? Then Aspire is exactly what you need to check first. In any case, nothing really changes. You need to add the correct middleware to the ASP.NET Core pipeline. This isn't done through project references, it's done by registering that middleware. You can easily mix up APIs and UI, just by adding the correct calls, eg adding `AddControllers` or some minimal APIs to a Blazor project. Its a *lot* easier and cleaner to put the Admin UI into a separate project though. Just check the Dashboard project

Comment: How Swagger UI is related?? I'll check that project, but it seems that you're not addressing my specific problem...

Comment: Swagger UI is a helper UI for an API project that otherwise doesn't provide a UI. I'm asking whether that's what you want to do, add some kind of admin or settings UI to your API projects.